# How to make an object completely transparent?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I want an object to not be visible **at all** in a render. I am trying to contain some particles in a simulation and I need them to not get out of the enclosure so I want a transparent object there (when I render) to prevent them from escaping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following material setup should give you a completely *Transparent* material that cannot be affected by light etc.

[image]

You can add a material and set the specularity and alpha to 0 and disable shadows but the easiest way is to *not* render the object at all. Open the *Outliner* and untick the camera beside the object.

[image]

Comment: I don't use Cycles much but I believe you can use a _Transparent BSDF_ to get a transparent material.