# How to render mesh that's inside another mesh?

Tags: rendering, modifiers

I'm looking for a way to render a mesh that resides inside another mesh, here is an image of what I mean:

[image]

I want the part of the monkey that is inside the cube to be rendered, so the result would look like this:

[image]

I know, I could achieve this using boolean operators, but this is prone to error due to not closed meshes, also because I will have cases, where multiple objects will lie inside the boundaries.

Is there any other way I could achieve this?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/how-can-i-easily-animate-cutaway-views-on-multiple-objects/8636#8636 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6550/cutting-with-boolean-modifiers

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using [render layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfbDL.jpg):
[image: Object ID and Transparent color]

1. Give the cube a [transparent material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5350/how-to-make-an-object-completely-transparent).
2. Give each object a different object index for masking with the [object ID mask](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-use-an-object-as-a-mask) in the node editor (Properties Window --> Object tab --> Relations --> Pass Index).
3. Render, go to the node editor and set up a node tree as in the attached image or [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37840).

Comment: Could you share a blend file of that?

Comment: Oh, I see the result in the background. That's certainly not what I want.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, didn't see the 2nd image you posted. This is still attainable with render layers, will update my answer in a bit to show how.

Comment: Edited, have a look and see if this works for you.

Comment: Yup, exactly what I wanted, now I'll have to figure out what you did there :). Sorry for posting this comment from a different accout, I'm having some serious problems tracking my SO accounts. I would certainly accept this answer if I could...
Nevertheless, really, thanks a lot! :D

Comment: No prob. Added some links to help you get into grips with each individual step.

Comment: @TLousky Unfortunately I was too fast saying it was working. Problem is, when I put the monkey behind the cube (relative to the camera), the monkey still renders while not being in the cube. Nevertheless, thanks for your efforts. :)

Comment: @spectre I know you don't need this anymore, but for academic purposes: you can use a copy of that cube with its normals flipped, and do a depth masking of the monkey on top of the object-index masking (so when behind the flipped cube, the moneky gets masked).